# Adding an Object to an Object Array

Tags: java, arrays, object

Goal: Add a new Movie object to an existing Movie[] if there is room to add.

Code:

```
    // Create the new Movie object
    Movie movieToAdd = new Movie (newTitle, newYear);

    // Add it to the Array
    count = addMovie(movieList, movieToAdd, count);
```

Method Code:

```
    public static int addMovie (Movie[] movieArray, Movie addMe, int count)
{
    if (count != movieArray.length)
    {
        count++;
        movieArray[count] = addMe;
        System.out.println("Movie added successfully!");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Array size of " + movieArray.length + " is full. Could not add movie.");
    }


    return count;
}
```

QUESTION:
Currently, when the movieList array is printed out, the new entry prints as null even though the created Movie object will print just fine outside of the way. Therefore, I'm assuming the best way to add the addMe object into the array is to create a second new Movie object initialized within the array and build it piece by piece (so addMe will remain in memory, and a "copy" of addMe will be set into the array).

This to me doesn't feel very efficient (I hate extra data laying about...). Is there a better way to do this?

NOTE: The Movie object actually has 10 private data members. For this exercise I only needed to pass in two parameters and set defaults for the rest. You can imagine why I don't to use ten GET statements to build this array and have extra objects stuck in memory...

EDIT:
Current Print Out (Portions):

```
    Menu options:
1.  Show all movies: 
2.  Show movies sorted - manual
3.  Show movies sorted - auto
4.  Show Movie by Index
5.  Search for movie Linearly
6.  Search for movie using Binary Search
7.  Add a movie
20. Quit 
Please choose an option from the menu: 1 to 20: 
7
Let's add the information for the new movie. Give me a Title and 4-digit Year, and I'll fill in the rest.
Title? 
Me
Year of Release? 
Please enter a valid 4 digit year: 1000 to 9999: 
1213
Movie added successfully!
Menu options:
1.  Show all movies: 
2.  Show movies sorted - manual
3.  Show movies sorted - auto
4.  Show Movie by Index
5.  Search for movie Linearly
6.  Search for movie using Binary Search
7.  Add a movie
20. Quit 
Please choose an option from the menu: 1 to 20:




25 | Les Vampires (1915)                   | Louis Feuillade                               | "Edouard Mathe, Marcel Levesque"                                                                                                                                                          | 1915 |   0 | http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0006206/          | http://www.guardian.co.uk/film/movie/117077/vampires                               | France       | Horror               | 175
null | 176
=============================================================================
```

MORE EDITS:
Constructor and Setters code - all this SHOULD be working right though.

```
    public Movie (String t, int y)
{
//  passed in
    this.title = setTitle(t);
    this.year = setYear(y);

//  defaults
    this.ranking = 0;
    this.director = "No Director";
    this.actors = "No Actors";
    this.oscars = 0;
    this.linkIMDB = "No IMDB Link";
    this.linkGuardian = "No Guardian Link";
    this.country = "No Country";
    this.genre = "No Genre";    
}

    public String setTitle (String newTitle)
{       
    if (newTitle == null)
    {
        this.title = "No Title";
    }
    else
    {
        this.title = newTitle;
    }

    return this.title;
}

    public int setYear (int newYear)
{
    if (newYear >= 999 && newYear <=10000)
    {
        this.year = newYear;
    }
    else
    {
        newYear = 0000;
    }

    return this.year;
}
```

Comment: _"when the movieList array is printed out, the new entry prints as null"_ What? Where? How? This code looks fine.

Comment: Yuriy `System.out.println` is a good hint ;)

Comment: why are you incrementing the count after checking to see if it's not equal to the length of the array?

Comment: This is Java. My bad, sorry -  I'm new here :P

Comment: Edit made to show output code

Comment: Note: the 25 before the Les Vampires is RANK of the movie, not INDEX. INDEX is at the end of the line (for ease of formatting, don't ask, I didn't like it this way but I'm more anal about my lines lining up than the index being in a feasible place....)

Comment: Unfortunately the only thing that is clear is that you happen to print null somewhere. It is not clear what you mean when you seem to differentiate between "in memory" and "in the array". Are you familiar with how object references work in Java? When you assign objects that have been allocated, you are only assigning the references, and the objects will stay in heap memory until they are garbage collected. This happens automatically and you should not care about the efficiency of a tiny amount of extra memory usage.

Comment: Yes, I'm pretty sure. I know that the addMe is really just a reference to a memory location for the object. I know that I need to add the object to the array piece by piece. The assignment from my professor states that the object must be created outside of the method, then passed in, and the method adds the object to the array. What I want to know is if there is a better way than passing in the new object, then using that object as a getTitle() (etc) reference to create ANOTHER new object to pass into the array.

Comment: Your problem seems to be that you have a null value somewhere where you shouldn't. I can assure you that unless you mutate the movie objects are adding them to the array, the adding part is not the problem. I don't know why you would need to clone the objects at all. Could you explain that line of thinking?

Comment: I was thinking that because the addMe is a memory address and not the object itself, I needed to access each individual private data member to add the object to the array. It would look like movieArray[count] = new Movie (addMe.getRank(), addMe.getTitle(), addMe.getDirector(), addMe.getActors(), addMe.getYear(),
             addMe.getOscars(), addMe.getLinkI(), addMe.getLinkG(), addMe.getCountry(), addMe.getGenre()); - but I don't want to do this. I will post the constructor for this new object.

Comment: That is not the problem. By that line of thinking the `new` operator also just returns a "memory address" and not the object itself, so what is the point of copying? I think this may be an issue that you'll have to pry into yourself. Construct simpler test cases and set breakpoints in the code and try to see why you're getting null.

Comment: Let me try to explain it this way - I printed the new Movie object right after it was created. It prints out fine on it's own, when just calling Println on the variable. The array prints just fine initially as well. Its only printing null when passing in the new object - and even then, only on the index of the new object. Everything to this point works - I don't know how to break down adding it to the array further.

Comment: Actually I just tested searching for the new movie after it was supposedly added to the array - and it came up with NullPointerException. So the object itself is not being stored into the array.

Comment: Well, a correct search should not raise any exceptions so that doesn't really say much about the array. I really think you are making too many assumptions. Better to be sure and make use of the debugging tools of your IDE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GOT IT!

I was using Count to set the index at which the new movie was stored.
Original count was 176.
Last index was 175.
I was increment BEFORE setting the movie, so the movie was being set at index 177.
So 176 was getting skipped.

It was only printing to 176 because that was the actual count, which wasn't accounting for the skipped space (there was an extra object in the array that wasn't getting printed).

(Figured this out when I attempted adding 2 new Movie objects to the array and got a null and then the first object only on print).

Solved by switching the set and the increment:

```
if (count <= movieArray.length)
    {
        movieArray[count] = addMe;
        count++;
        System.out.println("Movie added successfully!");
    }
```

Comment: This has the same effect as @ZongZhengLi's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19330147/1281433), because the _value_ of `count++` is `count`'s _old_ value.  This is the point of the [_post_-increment operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Increment_and_decrement_operators).

Answer (score 1):

It isn't clear what you are asking, but this portion is incorrect:

```
count++;
movieArray[count] = addMe;
```

What if `movieArray.length` is 10, and `count` is 9? Then it will pass the `count != movieArray.length` check and then you will try to assign the element at index 10. Use post increment:

```
movieArray[count++] = addMe;
```

Comment: Count will always be less than the array size as it's a number generated when movies are initially read in from a file. See above comments.

Comment: @ChristinaKline That is not the only consequence; your code will also never assign to the first element at index 0.

Comment: This program starts by loading in 176 movies from eight different files. I simply want to be able to add to this list. The assignment is to first create an object and then pass that object into a method that will add it to the existing list of movies.

Comment: It prints out correctly - except the added movie prints out as Null instead of printing the information. I've added a snippet from the output. that 176 is the new index number - it is correct. But the information before it is null.

Comment: GOT IT!

I was using Count to set the index at which the new movie was stored.
Original count was 176.
Last index was 175.
I was increment BEFORE setting the movie, so the movie was being set at index 177.
So 176 was getting skipped.

It was only printing to 176 because that was the actual count, which wasn't accounting for the skipped space.

(Figured this out when I attempted adding 2 new Movie objects to the array and got a null and then the first object only).

Solved by switching the set and the increment.

Comment: Your fix wasn't quite it, though it was close. I couldn't increment at ALL before or while setting the object. It had to be after.

Comment: @ChristinaKline `movieArray[count++] = addMe;` is _equivalent_ to `int temp = count; count++; movieArray[temp] = addMe`; which is functionally equivalent to `movieArray[count] = addMe; count++;`, which you posted in [your answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19337606/1281433) 15 hours after Zong Zheng Li's. You should [accept an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).  In my opinion, it should be Zong Zheng Li's, but either way, since your question is answered, you should accept an answer.